# What is the best way to initialise value of an Array dynamically in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I want to initialize the `Array` value dynamically and not hardcore it. How should I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using **Variable Operation** command.

Select the array variable and then select the Reinitialize radio button.
Put the new row(s) and column(s) values.

[image]